# executing query from docker to psql db shows psql: warning: extra command-line argument "" ignored

Tags: postgresql, docker

Hi I am in my docker console and trying to run shell script to connect to PSQL DB and execute queries.

```
#!/bin/sh
query = "select * from default$default."LightZone"";
#psql -U postgres -p postgres psql -e "$query";
```

This is my tablecreation.sh file and when I do ./tablecreation.sh

**./tablecreation.sh: 5: ./tablecreation.sh: query: not found
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "" ignored
Password for user prisma: 
psql (10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.**

The above message comes . But the same query is running from the psql command prompt.

can someone help me if i am missing something . I want to connect to postgres->prisma db >default$default schema > LightZone table  and run some queries.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the double quotes with `\`

```
query = "select * from default$default.\"LightZone\"";
```